# Best way to retrieve XML tag values

Tags: xml, parsing

I want to retrieve tag values in XML. Here we have many options (SAX, DOM, etc.) for this. But I want to use XPath (follows Document Object Model - DOM) to retrieve the information directly with an expression. Here the problem could be a space issue. In my understanding XPath stores the complete XML in memory and processes the requirement. This is a major impact if we have large XML files. Is there an easier way (other than SAX) to retrieve the elements?

Comment: You might want to add a tag for your language/platform (Java, C#, C++, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If it's in `Java` you might consider `XmlBeans`. You can access the value using XPath or the generated method by `XmlBeans`. http://xmlbeans.apache.org/